# GWT ImageBundle assertion: "No ImageRect"

Tags: gwt

I'm no longer able to run my application in developer mode. When trying to add my Image bundle with GWT.create() I get an assertion in ImageResourceGenerator.addImage(), "No ImageRect"

I've traced this through as far as I could, and I get into the MemoryCacheImageInputStream constructor, and it bombs out on the line Disposer.addRecord()

It works fine when compiled with gwtc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running on Ubuntu x86_64, and I had somehow inadvertantly uninstalled the package ia32-libs. Reinstalled ia32-libs using apt-get and it's working again :-)